# Structuring data in a conversion app

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, architecture, structure

In an application I need to convert values between metric, British imperial and US imperial, e.g. kilos to stones + pounds (UK) to pounds (US). How best to store the user-inputted data?

Is it better to convert all inputted values to e.g. metric and save as a float, or keep the user inputted data as say a literal string and interpret on each application launch?

The maths/equations etc is all good, it's more knowing what the most efficient structure is for **storing values that can be represented in different ways**, in a database?

Comment: I suggest to store metric values as a "String" in database. Because some times internal representation of number from one platform to other platform loses minor decimal value.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure whether to have a single "common denominator" numeric system, or just keep values as strings and then have the logic interpret on a case by case basis.

Comment: String is the best datatype when working with decimal numbers. You can then convert string to number in your platform.

Comment: @Kampai Depends what you mean by best. If you wish to preserve insane precision it may be a good choice, but performance-wise it's terrible.

Comment: put on hold for being opinion based? There must be one particular way of structuring data that is more efficient than another, it only invites opinion insofar as I and others lack the expertise to give a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really comes down to what precision you need. Storing the value as String might be safe but is extremely inefficient. For simple 1 to 1 value conversions it might be efficient enough. For converting thousands of values it probably won't.

I would go with scalar types representing the most complex value the user is able to enter manually. Derive calculations from those original values to avoid losing complexity.

One note: since you're dealing with real world values (I presume), ditch the sign and use the unsigned variants if you're going with scalar value types.

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach I use, Make an NSObject called WeightObject that have 2 propertiesL

1- the value the user entered (for example 3)

2- a unit the user used example:(KiloGrams/pounds etc..).

lastly save the object. this way yo keep the record exactly as user entred, and you make the method inside the object to return the value in KG or in punds etc...

so later you say float x = myWeightObject.KilosValue